# Angular testing of mat-tree

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm writing test cases for my project which uses mat-tree.
For some reason I'm unable to fetch the mat-tree-node from the mat-tree using fixture.debugElement. Any idea on how to solve this ?
Cannot share code as it is company work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Use test harnesses**

The only way I found was using harnesses. Its pretty simple & you can find an example on the angular site at the "Testing with MatTreeHarness" section when you press the Button to get the code (https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples):

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {TestbedHarnessEnvironment} from '@angular/cdk/testing/testbed';
import {MatTreeHarness} from '@angular/material/tree/testing';
import {HarnessLoader} from '@angular/cdk/testing';
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {TreeHarnessExample} from './tree-harness-example';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';

describe('TreeHarnessExample', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TreeHarnessExample>;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatTreeModule, MatIconModule],
      declarations: [TreeHarnessExample],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TreeHarnessExample);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  });

  it('should get correct number of children and descendants', async () => {
    const tree = await loader.getHarness(MatTreeHarness);
    const treeDescendants = await tree.getNodes();

    // flat nodes are not rendered until expanded
    expect(treeDescendants.length).toBe(2);

    await treeDescendants[0].expand();

    expect((await tree.getNodes()).length).toBe(5);
  });

  it('should correctly get correct node with text', async () => {
    const tree = await loader.getHarness(MatTreeHarness);
    const treeNodes = await tree.getNodes({text: /Flat Group/});
    expect(treeNodes.length).toBe(2);
    const secondGroup = treeNodes[0];

    expect(await secondGroup.getText()).toBe('Flat Group 1');
    expect(await secondGroup.getLevel()).toBe(1);
    expect(await secondGroup.isDisabled()).toBe(false);
    expect(await secondGroup.isExpanded()).toBe(false);
  });

  it('should correctly get tree structure', async () => {
    const tree = await loader.getHarness(MatTreeHarness);

    expect(await tree.getTreeStructure()).toEqual({
      children: [{text: 'Flat Group 1'}, {text: 'Flat Group 2'}],
    });

    const firstGroup = (await tree.getNodes({text: /Flat Group 1/}))[0];
    await firstGroup.expand();

    expect(await tree.getTreeStructure()).toEqual({
      children: [
        {
          text: 'Flat Group 1',
          children: [{text: 'Flat Leaf 1.1'}, {text: 'Flat Leaf 1.2'}, {text: 'Flat Leaf 1.3'}],
        },
        {text: 'Flat Group 2'},
      ],
    });
  });
});
```